# Did Calumet distribute Lee filters?

Tags: filters, lee

Did Calumet distribute Lee filters in the past? There are couple of Lee color correction filters I'm looking at purchasing, but they are in Calumet pouches. I asked the seller and he said that Calumet used to distribute Lee filters in the USA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> he said that Calumet used to distribute Lee filters in the USA

That is correct. Here is from one of my orders from 2013

```
LE6150  Calumet 4x4 CC50M Resin Filter  $74.99  4   $299.96
```